Module '"ai"' has no exported member 'OpenAIStream'
I have been trying to import "OpenAIStream" and "StreamingTextResponse" from 'ai' package in next js, but I get this error:
Attempted import error: 'StreamingTextResponse' is not exported from 'ai' (imported as 'StreamingTextResponse').

the version of 'ai' package is "ai": "^4.0.22",
Here is my code:
import  {OpenAIStream, StreamingTextResponse} from "ai";

   const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-4",
      stream: true,
      messages: [template, ...messages],
    });

    const stream = OpenAIStream(response);
    return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);

What I am doing wrong?

StreamingTextResponse has been removed in AI SDK 4.0. Use streamText.toDataStreamResponse() instead.
Using streamText
import { openai } from '@ai-sdk/openai';
import { streamText } from 'ai';

const { textStream } = streamText({
  model: openai('gpt-4-turbo'),
  prompt: 'Invent a new holiday and describe its traditions.',
});

for await (const textPart of textStream) {
  process.stdout.write(textPart);
}

Reference:
https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs/reference/stream-helpers/streaming-text-response

Man the docs on this are all over the place. This page uses toDataStream() (throws 500 error saying it's not returning a response), this one uses StreamingTextResponse, and I have yet to run into a page that uses the one you mention.
